# Can I use delegate in jquery for future context elements?

Tags: jquery

I know that in deleate i need first to get the context selector like:

```
 $("#Mydiv").delegate(...
```

But what if i even **dont have**  $("#Mydiv") ?

What if `$("#Mydiv")` should come from the server **in future time** ?

If i put it **Now** on the page , will it work in the **future** when $("#Mydiv") will come in ajax from ther server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `$("#MyDiv").live('click', function() {})`.

Live works by binding all events to the document element, so that events are handled after they bubble up through the DOM. Under the hood, `.live()` is really just calling `$(document).delegate("#MyDiv", 'click', function() {})`.

Comment: so if the container doesnt exists in my page - there is no point of using delegate... is that correct ?

Comment: correct. `.delegate()` works by binding to an object. if that object doesn't exist, delegate won't work. `.live()` gets around that by delegating to the `document` object, which is guaranteed to be available.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) if #MyDiv doesnt exists at all. Or delegate on another element that always exists on your page.